# How can I put my MacBook Air into clamshell mode when it's open and working?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, clamshell

I can put my MacBook into clamshell mode by just close it and sending some USB/Bluetooth signals.

However, sometimes I want to get into the mode directly without those actions. Is there no button or menu written "Get clamshell mode now"? Or utility?

Comment: What are you meaning when you say Clamshell mode?  Do you just want to kill the internal display and only use the external?  Because that’s essentially the only difference...Command F1 will let you cycle through the display modes (mirrored, extended, internal display off, etc)

Comment: @peelman Your answer is just what I have been found. Thanks! How about to make answer with the reply text? I'll pick it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you meaning when you say Clamshell mode? Do you just want to kill the internal display and only use the external? Because that’s essentially the only difference...Command F1 will let you cycle through the display modes (mirrored, extended, internal display off, etc)

Comment: Command-F1? Doesn't do anything on my machine (only when external display is connected?). (Fn-)F1 reduces brightness..?

Comment: It should at least be causing a Screen Detection, even if there’s no monitor attached.  You sure you haven’t modified a shortcut key to lay over top of it?  http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8525.html

Comment: oh, and: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3131

Comment: ⌘F1 only toggles screen mirroring on my MacBook Air. Maybe [something changed on 10.7](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110901113922148).

Answer (score 1):

My favourite utility to do this is an app called [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo), which silently sits in the menubar, and, when enabled, prevents the laptop from sleeping when the lid is closed. I haven't had much success with the *automatic* clamshell mode, and I'd use this instead.